# Is there any well-ordered uncountable set of real numbers under the original ordering?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I know that the usual ordering of $\mathbb R$ is not a well-ordering but is there an uncountable $S\subset \mathbb R$ such that S is well-ordered by $<_\mathbb R$?

Intuitively I'd say there is no such set but intuitively I'd also say there is no well-ordered uncountable set at all, which is obviously wrong. I still struggle to grasp the idea of an uncountable, well-ordered set.

Comment: FYI, a frequently asked question on the Indiana University (Bloomington) Ph.D. real variables qualifying exams back in the late 1960s to the mid 1970s was to prove that any well-ordered subset of the reals is countable. (Sometimes the question was whether an uncountable well-ordered subset of the reals exists, and you were to prove your answer.)

Comment: The proof of the well ordering theorem relies on the axiom of choice. Because of this we know that every set can be well ordered but not the explicit construction of the well order. So we cannot write down the exact well ordering of an uncountable set, we just know that one exists and then can use the properties that being able to well order the set gives us

Comment: @Matt Dyer: akkarin is asking whether there exists such a set on the real line, not whether there exists such a set somewhere.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes but the well ordering theorem states that every set can be well ordered and since any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a set this theorem says it will have a well order

Comment: **Hint:** You can get a pairwise disjoint collection of open intervals by picking one open interval lying between each of the points and the next point of the well ordered set.

Comment: @Matt Dyer: True, but the ordering you get may not have the numbers being in the same order as they appear on the number line, which is what akkarin wants.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro you're right, I missed his specification that the usual ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ must be used when reading the question

Comment: Why the vote to close? It's possible this is a duplicate (I vaguely remember the same question being asked earlier), but it's certainly not off-topic.

Comment: @Noah: Nor is it without context.

Comment: I think I get why this was closed as lacking context - it could be a homework problem that the OP has put very little thought into - but I don't think it's clear that's the case. This is a natural problem that the OP could have heard, or even thought of on their own; and for set theory questions like this, I think [incomprehension] is not necessarily indicative of lack of effort. I think we should give the OP the benefit of the doubt, and I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not enrolled in a set theory course but I'm preparing for an advanced one I'll be taking next year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There can't be. If $S\subseteq \Bbb R$ is well-ordered by the usual ordering, for every element $s_{\alpha}\in S$ that has an immediate successor $s_{\alpha+1}\in S$ (every element of $S$ except the greatest element if there is one), the set of rationals $Q_{\alpha}$ between the element and its successor is nonempty: $(s_{\alpha}, s_{\alpha+1}) \cap \Bbb Q \ne \emptyset$, and the $Q_{\alpha}$ are disjoint. If $S$ were uncountable, then $\bigcup_{\alpha < length(S)} Q_{\alpha}$ would also be uncountable — impossible, as it's a subset of $\Bbb Q$.